# How to customize action bar

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to stylize action bar. I am referring this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html). I created a simple android project using eclipse to test the customization. Here is  my res/values/themes.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#ff0000</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#ff0000</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar title text -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
           parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">#00ff00</item>
        <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar tabs text -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTabText"
           parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:textColor">#0000ff</item>
        <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

My manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testactionbar"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The result is pretty disappointing: [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxF6U6ikvhPCM2dDc2xSbzBkWk0/view?usp=sharing). The styling does not seem to have any effect. Am I missing something?

Edit:

Initially I had deleted android:action* elements because I was getting compilation errors and I thought those are required only for later versions of api. As suggested by @Furqan I cleaned and built again and the errors vanished! But now 
I am getting [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxF6U6ikvhPCczltS2k5NUMtZms/view?usp=sharing):

The menu items have not changed.

Comment: I was hoping to change the menu text color with actionMenuTextColor ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code for your theme

```
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#0000ff</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#0000ff</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar title text -->
<style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
       parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#0000ff</item>
    <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
</style>

<!-- ActionBar tabs text -->
<style name="MyActionBarTabText"
       parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">#0000ff</item>
    <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
</style>
```

if any error clean your project then run
 You can change the color of menu text easily by using`SpannableString`

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);

int positionOfMenuItem = 0; // or whatever...
MenuItem item = menu.getItem(positionOfMenuItem);
SpannableString s = new SpannableString("My red MenuItem");
s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, s.length(), 0);
item.setTitle(s);
}
```